# how to stop jqgrid multiselect on rows,only check box should be used to select row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

how to stop jqgrid multiselect on rows,only check box should be used to select row
my code is

```
 url:'asf/dsfs/'+json,
 datatype: "json",
    colNames:['id','title', 'start', 'stop','completed'],
    colModel:[
     {name:'id',index:'id', width:15,hidden:true, align:"center"},
     {name:'title',index:'title', width:150, align:"center"},
     {name:'start',index:'start', width:350, align:"center", sorttype:"date"},
     {name:'fine',index:'fine', width:350, align:"center", sorttype:"date"},
     {name:'completed',index:'completed', width:120, align:"center",formatter:highlight},//il solitoformatter:infractionInFormatter},  
    ],
    //rowNum:8,
    //rowList:[8,10,20,30],
    pager: '#pagerJobList',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
 multiselect: true,
 subGrid: false,
 autowidth: true,
 height: 250,
 rowheight: 300,
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Do you want to prevent unselecting of the rows which have been selected before?

Answer (score 0):

set this properties to in jqgrid it will work fine
    multiselect: true,

multiboxonly: true,

=>this property is useful only selection bycheck box and not by body if you senlect by body then single selection will work..